# beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I am making an application where audio will play in the background. In the following code, bgTask is undeclared. What kind of object should bgTask be?

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application 
{
    UIApplication  *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{ 
        [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask]; 
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{});

    [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask]; 
    bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}
```

Comment: please format your code in the right way.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to declare bgTask before you assign:

```
UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = 0;
```

Comment: thanks. I want to spank myself every time I read one of these vague docs written by Apple (~90% of their docs). They should hire people who know how to write docs.

Comment: You want to spank yourself..?

Comment: @willcodejavaforfood I have tried this code with a timer but timer stops after round 10 minutes how can I continue it in a long time

Comment: Just to clarify, it should be `UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = 0;` since it is a `NSUInteger`.

Answer (score 10):

I cannot comment on previous answers, however to initialize UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier you should not set it to nil or 0. You should set it to:

```
UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
```

In the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html) UIBackgroundTaskInvalid says it should be used to initialize variables or to check for errors.

Comment: `UIBackgroundTaskInvalid = 0x0000000000000000`. Same thing.

Comment: @duci9y believe me, you don't want magic numbers in your code. Stick to constants provided by API.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the bgTask in the block so you have to declare it like this..

```
__block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = 0;
```

`__block` will allow this variable to use in the block method. And its have double underscore.