# iphone - how to send a sms message at a scheduled time

Tags: iphone, ios, timer, datepicker, uipickerview

I am creating an application where user can send an SMS to the Recipient, and it is working fine. But I want to send Message at a scheduled time. For this I have two picker views, from one picker sender we can set date and from other sender can set time as I have shown in the attached screenshot.

How to trigger send button or send the sms at a scheduled time?  Can I use an NSTimer?

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you. If someone have any doubt related to question then let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NSTimer` to schedule message.

```
+ (NSTimer *)scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds target:(id)target selector:(SEL)aSelector userInfo:(id)userInfo repeats:(BOOL)repeats
```

here you can pass target as Your view controller that has sms sending functionality and selector will be your action method that gets called on sms button click.

But problem with `NSTimer` is that it stops when App is in background.If you have such requirement then `NSTimer` will not be useful.

Comment: What about using local notification instead of NSTimer? I haven't used, but just for curiosity...it will work, rt?

Comment: Local notification are delivered only when app is in background.App will not receive local notification in foreground mode.

Comment: No,i think only notification wont be displayed when app in foreground, but didReceiveRemoteNotification will be invoked in both cases from which he can send sms.

Comment: Thanks to all for giving me time.Finally i am using NSTimer but the problem is how to calculate NSTimeInterval in seconds? According to my requirement i can't use Local notification.

Comment: NSTimeInterval is itself in seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You can use NSTimer in background also...
You need to make some changes in appDelegate...
Follow the below link to make your app wait for background task to complete
[beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871149/beginbackgroundtaskwithexpirationhandler)
for long time in background try (more than 10 min)
[How do I make my App run an NSTimer in the background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9220494/how-do-i-make-my-app-run-an-nstimer-in-the-background)

Comment: But in this case timer will not work for too long. It will work for max 10 mins.

Comment: @Jitesh Your point is right, Application can stay in background for 10 min max, .....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9220494/how-do-i-make-my-app-run-an-nstimer-in-the-background

Comment: @Anand are you using iphone SDK to send SMS?, Apple doesn't allow automatic sending of SMS... in that case You can see similar failed app on appstore https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/smartsender-schedule-your/id490395840?mt=8